# How do I efficiently add random vertical segments into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to simulate rain using NumPy, they say an image is more than a thousand words so here is a description longer than two thousand words:

[image]

[image]

I already wrote the code, but I think my implementation is inefficient, so I want to know if NumPy has any builtin functions that can speed up the process:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from random import random, randbytes

def rain(width, strikes=360, color=True, lw=3):
    assert not width % 16
    height = int(width * 9 / 16)
    img = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    half = height / 2
    for i in range(strikes):
        x = round(random() * width)
        y = round(height - random() * half)
        x1 = min(x + lw, width - 1)
        if color:
            rgb = list(randbytes(3))
        else:
            rgb = (178, 255, 255)
        img[0:y, x:x1] = rgb
    
    return img

img1 = Image.fromarray(rain(1920))
img1.show()
img1.save('D:/rain.jpg', format='jpeg', quality=80, optimize=True)

img2 = Image.fromarray(rain(1920, color=False))
img2.show()
img2.save('D:/rain_1.jpg', format='jpeg', quality=80, optimize=True)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, if you set `lw` to 1 and use a 1-channel indexed/grayscale image instead of a 3-channel, your code will run several times faster. Do you really need these requirements? These are good for visualization, but do not seem to be essential for simulation.

Comment: @ken Well, I do want an RGB image so greyscale is no go. I am creating art using programming. Do you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to improve by 2 to 4 times faster.

1. Since raindrops do not stop in the upper half of the image, the upper half can be stretched out from the lower half after all strikes end.
2. Since broadcasting tuples is relatively slow, use 32-bit format color instead.

```py
def rain(width=1920, strikes=360, color=True, lw=3):
    assert not width % 16
    height = int(width * 9 / 16)
    img = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint32)
    half = height / 2
    upper_bottom = int(half) - 1
    alpha = 255 << 24

    # Paint background.
    # The upper half will always be overwritten and can be skipped.
    img[upper_bottom:] = alpha

    for i in range(strikes):
        x = round(random() * width)
        y = round(height - random() * half)
        x1 = min(x + lw, width - 1)
        if color:
            # Pack color into int. See below for details.
            rgb = int.from_bytes(randbytes(3), 'big') + alpha
        else:
            # This is how to pack color into int.
            r, b, g = 178, 255, 255
            rgb = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16) + alpha

        # Only the lower half needs to be painted in this loop.
        img[upper_bottom:y, x:x1] = rgb

    # The upper half can simply be stretched from the lower half.
    img[:upper_bottom] = img[upper_bottom]

    # Unpack uint32 to uint8 x4 without deep copying.
    img = img.view(np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))

    return img
```

Note:

- Endianness is ignored. May not work on some platforms.
- Performance is greatly degraded if the image **width** is very large.
- If you are going to convert `img` to `PIL.Image`, compare its performance too as it is also improved.

Because of the rain overlaps each other (which makes removing for-loop hard) and because the strikes are not so many (which makes the room for improvement small), I find it difficult to optimize further. Hopefully this is enough.

Comment: I did a profile of OP’s vs. my latest code (in the answer below) with “strikes” set to 100,000 (plots disabled) and it was 14 times faster.  Let me know what you think!

Comment: Your code does not correctly replicate rain overlap. I haven't tried but I think you will see some rain has more than one color. Also, I'm not sure the OP wants 100k strikes, as he/she is creating art. These two are the main reasons why the OP's code is difficult to optimize, so I have no doubt that "optimization" ignoring these requirements will achieve better results. In other words, I can only assure that my answer performs well only when these requirements are the actual requirements.

Comment: I solved the overlap issue by converting the array of random integers to a set to remove duplicates, and then back to a sorted list.  Also, I agree that they didn’t want that many; I was just proving that my algorithm scaled up better.  I didn’t measure the performance at 360 “strikes”, but I would imagine it would still be significantly faster than OP’s.

Comment: I'm sure there are faster approaches when scaled up, but your approach is simply wrong. Consider the case where `x` is always the same value and `y` is `height - index_of_strike` (i.e. rain gets shorter each time). In this case, a rain of colorful horizontal stripes should be created and there will be no removable duplicates. Your approach obviously cannot replicate this behavior. Because you are not correctly replicating rain overlap. And, I hate to say this, but at 360 strikes your code may be slower than the OP's. Optimization on a small scale is a completely different task, you know.

Comment: Think about it this way, this is a 2-D snapshot of simulated rain.  How often does all the rain fall in one spot?  I think you are missing the point of this question.  I made the assumption that more than one strike in the same location did not need more than one length and color combination.  Should I have asked the OP?  Probably, but it seemed a reasonable assumption.  But I did recognize that my speed-up calculation was in fact incorrect and misleading.  I will fix that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to speed up code using NumPy is to utilize broadcasting and element-by-element operations, so that less efficient for-loops can be avoided.  Below is a performance comparison between my algorithm (rain2) and OP’s (rain1):

```
import numpy.random as npr
from random import random, randbytes
from PIL import Image
import profile

def rain1(width, strikes=360, color=True, lw=3):
    assert not width % 16
    height = int(width * 9 / 16)
    img = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    half = height / 2
    for i in range(strikes):
        x = round(random() * width)
        y = round(height - random() * half)
        x1 = min(x + lw, width - 1)
        if color:
            rgb = list(randbytes(3))
        else:
            rgb = (178, 255, 255)
    img[0:y, x:x1] = rgb
    
    return img


def rain2(width, strikes=360, color=True, lw=3):
    assert not width % 16
    height = width*9//16
    [inds,] = np.indices((width,))
    img = np.zeros((height, width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    img[:,:,3] = 255
    half = height/2
    # randint from numpy.random lets you 
    # define a lower and upper bound, 
    # and number of points.
    x = list(set(npr.randint(0, width-lw-1, (strikes,))))
    x = np.sort(x)
    y = npr.randint(half, height, (len(x),))
    if color:
        rgb = npr.randint(0, 255, (len(x), 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    else:
        rgb = np.array([178, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    for offset in range(lw):
        img[:,x+offset,3] = 0
        img[:,x+offset,:3] = rgb
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
        img[0:yi,xi:xi+lw,3] = 255
    return img


def example_test_old(strikes, disp_im=True):
    img1 = Image.fromarray(rain1(1920, strikes=strikes))
    if disp_im: img1.show()
    img1.save('rain1.jpg', format='jpeg', quality=80, optimize=True)

    img2 = Image.fromarray(rain1(1920, strikes=strikes, color=False))
    if disp_im: img2.show()
    img2.save('rain1.jpg', format='jpeg', quality=80, optimize=True)


def example_test_new(strikes, disp_im=True):
    img1 = Image.fromarray(rain2(1920, strikes=strikes))
    if disp_im: img1.show()
    img1.save('rain2.png', format='png', quality=80, optimize=True)
    
    img2 = Image.fromarray(rain2(1920, strikes=strikes, color=False))
    if disp_im: img2.show()
    img2.save('rain2.png', format='png', quality=80, optimize=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Execute only if this module is not imported into another script
    example_test_old(360)
    example_test_new(360)
    
    profile.run('example_test_old(100000, disp_im=False)')
    profile.run('example_test_new(100000, disp_im=False)')
```

On my PC this speeds it up by a factor of 14.5!
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to fix your code, the first exception is `height` is not iterable, I used `range(height)`, then I got this: `ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1081`, both exceptions were raised by this line: `inds = np.indices(range(height))`

Comment: I am very experienced in Python but I only started actually learning Numpy, Matplotlib and Pandas a month ago or so, so I can't fix your code.

Comment: I fixed my code; it runs fine on my Windows 11 PC with Anaconda.

Comment: CORRECTION: after @ken replied to my comments on his answer, I revisited my code and found a few problems.  I would post the fixes to the issues I created, but my fixed code is in fact slower than OP's, just as ken guessed.  So disregard my code; the answer marked as correct is the best answer.